# Is it possible to take an integral with respect to a vector?

Tags: integration, functions, vector-analysis, differential-forms

If we consider a vector field **v** containing three polar components: $$\boldsymbol{v}=(r, \theta, \phi)$$ giving us the following circular field where *r* and *theta* are constant: [Sample field (top view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZzkV.jpg)$$\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{e}_r+\boldsymbol{e}_\theta+\phi\boldsymbol{e}_\phi$$
Is it possible to take an integral whose integrand *f* is a function of one or more of the components above with respect to our vector field **v**? For example, lets define *f*: $$f(r)=r^2$$
and plug *f* into the following indefinite integral: $$\int f(r)d\boldsymbol{v}$$ If possible, how can this expression be evaluated? I considered expanding **v** into its corresponding linear combination *(2)* thinking that might lead somewhere. Maybe taking an integral with respect to a vector could be thought of as being analogous to the directional derivative: $$\nabla_vf(r)$$ If it isn't possible, then could an alternative be to integrate *f* with respect to the flow curves generated by **v**? If so, what would that look like?

Any methods would be helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: What would it mean to integrate with respect to the vector? You can integrate a function along a curve or something but what is the region of integration?

Comment: @SuzuHirose I should've clarified this but what I'm trying to do is integrate a function along a flow curve generated by a particular vector field.

Comment: Wouldn’t you need to determine what a flow curve is, e.g. by solving a DEQ? There isn’t just “a” vector involved.

Comment: You can do a line integral; there are essentially two "types" (although one is a case of the other, technically). One is $\int_C f ds$, where $f$ is a scalar function, and the other is $\int_C \mathbf{f} \cdot d \mathbf{r}$ where $\mathbf{f}$ is a vector valued function. The latter is the same as $\int_C \mathbf{f} \cdot \mathbf{T} ds$ where $\mathbf{T}$ is the unit tangent vector (which depends on the orientation with which you traverse $C$ but not the speed).

Comment: (Cont.) Even though "vector line integrals" are a special case of "scalar line integrals", they are such a common thing to see in practice that they have their own notation and even some of their own theorems, including "the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals". Anyway if you don't have the curve $C$ already given then you need to trace out $C$ in order to integrate along it.